# Facebook Text Sharing With Custom Fonts

Tags: android, facebook, fonts, custom-font

My Application require is share text with **facebook**.I'm able to share text using  [this code](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing).
Here I'm giving parameters like this:

```
Bundle myParames = new Bundle();
myParames.putString("message", message);asyncFacebook.request("me/feed", myParames,"POST", new FacebookPostListener(), null);
```

But I want share the text every letter with corresponding font like,
if myString = "stack"; then,

```
String newString = null;
newString.replace("s", "Ⓢ");
newString.replace("t", "Ⓣ");
newString.replace("a", "Ⓐ");
newString.replace("c", "Ⓒ");
newString.replace("k", "Ⓚ");
```

Then I'm able to share my text with replaced fonts.
But I want apply font from .ttf file and then share.
I tried `SpannableString`, But it can't convert into `.string()`.
So I need to change library?

Answer (score 2):

Those characters you are doing your replacements with are no font, but characters. *Unicode characters*, to be precise.

> Enclosed C or circled Latin C (Ⓒ or ⓒ) is a typographical symbol. As one of many enclosed alphanumerics, the symbol is a "C" within a circle.
>   The capitalized symbol (Ⓒ) can be generated with the unicode encoding "U+24B8" and the UTF-8 (hex.) encoding "e2 92 b8".

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%92%B8

So, you are replacing one character with another, and that is all you can do.
You can't pass a custom font embedded in your text to another application through something like an intent. This is not possible.

Comment: i mean that how to share font typeface. same as me on the text. i haveing trouble while i m taking the SpannableString string object the i haveing share to that SpannableString to face book that is not possible.... so any idea about that ......